# Why don't these images accept display: inline property?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using WordPress **Twenty Sixteen** theme. I've created a page and now I have inserted 4 images in it. When I open the page, the images are displayed in vertical order, i.e., 1 above other. They aren't assigned **display: block** property either. I tried display: inline and display: inline-block properties, but they aren't working. These are clearly shown in inspect element, but they don't affect the elements. (Also, **float: left** works perfectly, but I want display: inline to work).

What is the problem and how can I solve it?
Here's the text written in the page:

```
<div id="gal-1">
<img src="http://localhost/microsoft/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/images/surface.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="http://localhost/microsoft/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/images/lumia.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="http://localhost/microsoft/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/images/windows.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="http://localhost/microsoft/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/images/edge.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Images are already `display: inline-block` by default. If your images are displayed in vertical order then you have some other code that's affecting the images.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please check your code i think there is break line 
 tag which is causing issue if you remove 
 it will display items inline block;

another solution

instead of using display:inline-block you can do like

```
#gal-1
{
display:flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
}
#gal-1 img
{
display:inline-flex;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It was the default break. I removed it after each image.

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you use this:

```
div#gal-1>img {
   display:inline;
}
```

This will match div gal-1 child when it is an img.
Use !important if necessary to override any display: block;